# Query not being executed inside php class function

Tags: php

Hi I am learning how to make a simple mvc with php, but seem to be running into a little trouble with executing the queries inside the class function.

When I take the codes out of the class function they work fine. But they dont work when the code is inside. Any ideas would be appreciated thanks.

```
<?php
include_once("model/book.php");

class Model {

public function getBookList()
{
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","Ory4n","","test");
if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT Title, Author, Description FROM books";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 echo '<h2 class="word">'.$row["Title"].'</h2>';
 echo '<h4 class="word">'.$row["Author"].'</h4>';
 echo '<p class="word">'.$row["Description"].'</p>';
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
} // close function

public function getBook($title)
{
 getBookList();
}
}
?>
```

Comment: In order to call the function from outside the class you have to create an instance of the class **$model = new Model();** and then call it 
**$model->getBookList();**

Comment: Or if you try to call it from inside the class, for example in the getBook function you have to do it like this **$this->getBookList();**

Comment: Hi, appreciate your assistance, Where do I create the instance? inside the getBookList function?

Comment: You create it wherever you need it, outside of the Model class. For example right after the last **}**

Comment: OMG thank you very much, it is now working. I have spent 2 days trying to get it going and researching what i was doing wrong. Really appreciate your help.

So Do I not add echo statements inside the getBookList function, only outside it?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do... You can leave them like that, or if you want to be more dynamic you can add them in an array and return the array for later use.

Comment: Oh I forgot I removed my array because I thought that is what the issue was why it wouldnt load lol. Thanks again I will put my array back. Do I add it inside the getBookList function?

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing the comments...

```
<?php
class Model {

    /**
     * @return array Empty array in case of no results
     */
    public function getBookList() {
        $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","Ory4n","","test");

        if($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        $sql = "SELECT Title, Author, Description FROM books";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        $books = array();

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $book = new stdClass();
                $book->title = $row['Title'];
                $book->author = $row['Author'];
                $book->description = $row['Description'];
                $books[] = $book;
            }
        }

        return $books;
    }
}

//Demo - how to use
$model = new Model();
$books = $model->getBookList();

foreach($books as $book) {
    echo '<h2 class="word">'.$book->title.'</h2>';
    echo '<h4 class="word">'.$book->author.'</h4>';
    echo '<p class="word">'.$book->description.'</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this code makes a lot more sense then mine. Appreciate the assistance, and I can actually understand the code the way you wrote it.

Comment: Hi, I don't have a reputation of 15 to upvote answer or something it said.